# How to stop a discord bot using discord.py and return a variable to another program?

Tags: discord.py

I created a bot to analyze messages sent to a text channel.
This bot is invoked by another program.
When the bot detects a specific phrase, I want to return that phrase and continue with the execution of the program that invoked it.
How can I do this?

```
def fromDiscord():
    discord_token = config.discord_token
    client = discord.Client()

    @client.event
    async def on_connect():
        print('Ready...')
    
    @client.event
    async def on_message(message):

        if 'specific phrase' in message.content:
            idx = message.content.index('specific phrase')
            phrase = message.content[idx: idx + 42]
            return phrase
        
    client.loop.run_until_complete(client.run(discord_token))
```

The bot works, detects the phrase but does not return the variable to the main program and, of course, does not stop executing.

Answer (score 0):

You could try using a [Queue](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#pipes-and-queues) from [Multiprocessing](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html).
And make the bot itself another [Process](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.Process)

create a queue (before starting the bot):

```py
myqueue = multiprocessing.Queue()
```

start the bot as another process:

```py
bot_process = multiprocessing.Process(target=fromDiscord, daemon=True) # Create the process, and make it a daemon, so that it exits if the main process exits

bot_process.start() # Start the process
```

and then instead of `return phrase`, you could use:

```py
myqueue.put(phrase)
await client.close() # Exit from discord
```

and on the other part of the code where you want to get the phrase:

```py
phrase = myqueue.get()

# and if the client.close() doesn't work, you can just use this:
bot_process.terminate()
# which will kill the process
```